# Draw in two tables vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working with program that will randomly choose who is making a Christmas gift to whom.

I've created an empty array. When you add a "player" it's pushing the name into two different arrays. Players[] and Players2[].

When you start a draw. The program writes the names of the Players[] on the left hand side and on the right side it writes the drawn names from Players2[].

Every Player from Players2[], after being drawn, is being deleted from the array so in the end we have an empty Players2[] array and full Players[] array.

The problem is: I can't make a working if statement that is checking if the person will not draw himself...

```js
let Players = [];
let Players2 = [];

const addBTN = document.getElementById('addBTN');
const onlyLetters = /^[a-zżźćóęśńłA-ZŻŹĆÓŁĘŚŃŁ ]+$/;
const refreshBTN = document.getElementById('refreshBTN');
const warningBTNyes = document.getElementById('warning-button-yes');
const warningBTNno = document.getElementById('warning-button-no');
const playersList = document.getElementById('playersList');
const playersList2 = document.getElementById('playersList2');
const startBTN = document.getElementById('startBTN');
const drawLotsBTN = document.getElementById('drawLotsBTN');

addBTN.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const input = document.getElementById('addPLAYER');
  const person = document.getElementById('addPLAYER').value;
  if (input.value == "") {
    console.log('error_empty_input');
    document.getElementById('errorMSG').style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById('errorMSG').innerHTML = "Wpisz imię osoby!";
  } else if (input.value.match(onlyLetters)) {
    console.log('good');
    Players.push(person);
    Players2.push(person);
    playersList.innerHTML = playersList.innerHTML + "<br>" + person;
    document.getElementById('addPLAYER').value = "";
    document.getElementById('errorMSG').style.color = "green";
    document.getElementById('errorMSG').innerHTML = "Powodzenie! Dodaj kolejną osobę.";
  } else {
    console.log('error_input');
    document.getElementById('errorMSG').style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById('errorMSG').innerHTML = "Coś jest nie tak z imieniem. Pamiętaj aby wprowadzać same litery!";
  }
});

refreshBTN.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('warning').style.display = "block";
});

warningBTNyes.addEventListener('click', function() {
  location.reload(true);
  document.getElementById('addPLAYER').value = "";
});

warningBTNno.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('warning').style.display = "none";
});

startBTN.addEventListener('click', function() {
  drawLotsBTN.disabled = false;
  const input = document.getElementById('addPLAYER');
  const person = document.getElementById('addPLAYER').value;
  if (input.value == "") {

  } else if (input.value.match(onlyLetters)) {
    console.log('good');
    Players.push(person);
    Players2.push(person);
    playersList.innerHTML = playersList.innerHTML + "<br>" + person;
    document.getElementById('addPLAYER').value = "";
    document.getElementById('errorMSG').style.color = "green";
    document.getElementById('errorMSG').innerHTML = "Powodzenie! Zaczynasz losowanie!";
  } else {
    console.log('error_input');
    document.getElementById('errorMSG').style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById('errorMSG').innerHTML = "Coś jest nie tak z imieniem. Pamiętaj aby wprowadzać same litery!";
  }
  document.getElementById('addPLAYER').disabled = true;
});

drawLotsBTN.addEventListener('click', function() {
  for (let i = 0; i = Players2.length; i++) {
    if (Players2.length > 0) {
      randomPerson = Math.floor(Math.random() * Players2.length);
      if (randomPerson != Players.indexOf(i)) {
        console.log(Players2[randomPerson]);
        playersList2.innerHTML = playersList2.innerHTML + "<br>" + Players2[randomPerson];
        Players2.splice(randomPerson, 1);
      }
    } else {
      console.log('error_empty_array');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="warning" class="warning">
  <div class="warning-flex">
    <h1>Wszelkie wpisane imiona zostaną usunięte</h1>
    <div class="warning-buttons">
      <button id="warning-button-yes" class="warning-button-yes">Tak</button>
      <button id="warning-button-no" class="warning-button no">Nie</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="lotteryContainer">
  <div class="left">
    <p>dodaj osobę</p>
    <div class="addPerson">
      <input required id="addPLAYER" type="text">
      <button id="addBTN">+</button>
      <p id="errorMSG"></p>
      <div class="refresh">
        <button id="refreshBTN">Od nowa</button>
        <button id="startBTN">Start</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>Uczestnicy</p>
    <div class="tables">
      <div class="tableLeft">
        <p id=playersList></p>
      </div>
      <div class="tableRight">
        <p id="playersList2"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button id="drawLotsBTN">Losuj</button>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now if I understand what your program aims to do, there is a simple algorithm for it.
How I understand your goal:
You have a list of persons who are going to give presents to each other. (like in secret Santa). It is random who will give to who, but each person gives and receives one gift.
How to implement it (i'd normaly use maps, but I am guessing you are more comfortable with arrays):

```js
players = ["Adam", "Bret", "Clay", "Donald"];
players.sort(function(a, b){return 0.5 - Math.random()}); // shuffles array
gives_to = [...players]; // copy values of array
gives_to.push(gives_to.shift()); // let the first element be the last
```

Here the first player (players[0]) will give to gives_to[0] and the second to gives_to[1] etc.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand how to make it work using your algorithm. 

The person fills names manually in the input and when he is finished, he clicks the "start" button to start drawing.

So I have one array, created by the user and the other one, a copy of it, that I want to draw from.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, sorry for a late response. I have problems fully understanding what you are looking for. I think part of it is the name of Players[] and Players2[] don't tell me what does what, and the non English part makes it so I have trouble testing what you have done already.

Can you specify exactly what you are having problems with?

Comment: I'll try to specify what my code does. I assume you have an array of players that are giving presents to each other. One way you could implement this is by letting the first player give to the second, the second to the third, ... , and the last to the first. This would ensure that everyone gives to a different person, and no-one can give to themselves (unless there is only one person, then the first and last person is the same).
This would be a bad way of doing it if you intend for it to be secret or random. That is why I shuffle the array. If not, then you don't need to shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

I've created this JS script trying to use Trygve Ruud algorithm but it doesn't work like desired.

```
drawLotsBTN.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(Players.length > 0) {
        console.log(Players)
        Players.sort(function(a, b){
            return 0.5 - Math.random();
        });
        for(let i = 0; i < Players.length; i++){
            playersList2.innerHTML = playersList2.innerHTML + "<br>" + Players[i];
        }
    }
    else{
        console.log('error_empty_array');
    }
    
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).